# click one of many buttons with the same class name in c#(webBrowser)

Tags: c#

how can i click the second one of many buttons with the same class name in C#(webBrowser)..

```
<li class="uJiz5"><button class="g56EM  _7_FaD"> 1.Button <span class="MICM7 reportSpriteChevron"></span></button></li>

<li class="uJiz5"><button class="g56EM  _7_FaD"> 2.Button <span class="MICM7 reportSpriteChevron"></span></button></li>

<li class="uJiz5"><button class="g56EM  _7_FaD"> 3.Button <span class="MICM7 reportSpriteChevron"></span></button></li>
```

C# code(this clicks just first button but I need to click second button):

```
foreach(HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
    {
        if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "g56EM  _7_FaD")
        {
            btn.InvokeMember("Click");
            break;
        }

    }
```

can you explain with sample code? thanks.

Comment: You `break` upon the first match. If you want the second match, use a counter and invoke the click when it is equal to 2 (or 1 if you start with 0). You can `break` afterwards if you don't want to invoke the click on any subsequent buttons.

Comment: @stickybit  can you give a code example, sir? "if (counter>1)" does not click on any button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `break` upon the first match. If you want the second match, use a counter and invoke the click when it is equal to 1 (if you start with 0). You can `break` afterwards if you don't want to invoke the click on any subsequent buttons. Something along the lines of:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
{
    if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "g56EM  _7_FaD")
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            btn.InvokeMember("Click");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```